# Associate a commit with sequentially triggered workflows

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I have two GitHub Actions workflows which run in sequence.

Is there any way to modify this so that I can see both workflows on the commit, even when they happen in sequence?

The upstream workflow is configured to trigger on pushes to main as follows

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'
```

and the downstream workflow triggers on the completion of the first

```yaml
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["upstream"]
    branches: [main]
    types: 
      - completed
```

But when I look in the commit history, only the upstream is associated with the commits. I can see the other workflows in the actions tab for the repo, but not on the commits.